# Longest word in sentence, potential equality of lengths

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
sentence = 'Cunning fox peels apples.'.strip('.')
def longest_word(target):
    set = max(target.split(), key=len)
    temp = [x for x in set]
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        if temp[i].isalpha() == True:
            count += 1
    return set,count
print(longest_word(sentence))
```

The code works if the longest word in a sentence is strictly longer in symbols than any other, however, how should I adjust the code if the sentence is something like:

```
sentence = 'Black bananas and green tomatos are red.'
```

How can I return that there are n words that are equally long? Obviously it's enough to count the symbols in one of the words, but the:

```
set = max(sentence.split(),key=len)
```

returns only the first of the longest words.

Comment: This code is as un-Pythonic as it can get. You should use `list(set)` instead of a list-comprehension in this case. `max(...)` will only give you one item of the passed list. Python for-loops can already iterate over the list `temp`, no need for the `range()`. You should also prefer not to compare with `True`

Comment: Some small comments to your code: 1) you should never compare to `True`, just do `if temp[i].isalpha(): ...`. 2) Instead of iterating over the length of `temp`, you can directly iterate over the letters of temp, so do `for letter in temp: if letter.isalpha(): ...`. 3) You don't even have to use a for-loop: `count = sum(1 for letter in temp if letter.isalpha())`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the un-pythonic style. I will improve on it, I have only recently begun using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to make two passes along the list of targets, once to get the maximum length, and then to select all words whose length matches the maximum:

```
def longest_words(targets):
    targets = targets.split()
    max_len = max(len(item) for item in targets)
    return set(item for item in targets if len(item) == max_len)
```

Quick test:

```
In [17]: sentence = 'Black bananas and green tomatos are red.'

In [18]: longest_words(sentence.strip('.'))
Out[18]: {'bananas', 'tomatos'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). It has a `groupby()` function that can be used to group an iterator based on a custom-defined function, in this case `len()`:

```
>>> sentence = 'Black bananas and green tomatos are red.'
>>> words = sorted(sentence.strip(".").split(), key=len)
>>> groups = [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(words, len)]
>>> groups
[['and', 'are', 'red'], ['Black', 'green'], ['bananas', 'tomatos']]
>>> groups[-1]
['bananas', 'tomatos']
```

Comment: This is a nice generalisation of the problem, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get maximum length, and check and fetch each word of the same length:

```
sentence = 'Black bananas and green tomatos are red.'.strip('.')
def longest_word(target):
    words = target.split()
    max_len = max([len(w) for w in words])
    return max_len, [w for w in words if len(w)==max_len]
print(longest_word(sentence))
```

You can also define a customized `len` function to count only characters,

```
def word_len(word):
    return len([c for c in word if c.isalpha()])
```

and replace `len` with `word_len` in the previous example.

Answer (score 0):

My function returns a list with the longest word or words.

```
def longest(sentence):
    ordered = sorted(sentence.split(), key=len)
    l = len(ordered[-1]) # the last, longest element
    m = [ordered[-1]]
    for elt in ordered[-2::-1]:
        if len(elt) < l : return m
        m.append(elt)
    return m
```